# How to search with information in jText field in java swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am making a jFrame Form which look like this: [image]

My question is how can i make the program execute the query in my database to look up information i need and put it in the under table after filling information in jtext field and pressing search button.

For example if i fill the supplier name field with D and supplier id with 123 it will appear the information of all suppliers that have the letter D and 123 first with name and id in the table

Thank you very much

Comment: I think you should sort result set of your table and then fire it again so the update will be visible.

Comment: From a DB query, execute it, create (or alter) a table model with the information, set the table to the model. Too broad for an SO Q&A. Too lazy a question not to down vote.

Comment: And by *"From a DB query, .."* I meant *"**Form** a DB query ,.."*

Comment: Pretty simple really.  You put a listener on the document that underlies the JTextFields.  You pass the field information from the GUI controller to the GUI model.  The GUI model fires off a request to the database code, which retrieves the information from the database,  The database code makes Java objects from the result set, and passes the Java objects from the database code to the GUI model.  The GUI model updates the GUI view with the new Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id=Integer.parseInt(txtid.getText().trim());
String name=txtsupplierid.getText().trim();
String query="select * from yourtablename "+
" where id="+id+" and suppliername like '%"+name+"%' ";
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
```

hope it works